# Java: Counting 'a' in char array, counter wrong value

Tags: java, arrays, count, char, letter

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    char[] array = {'а', 'g', 'r', 'e', 'r', 's', 'a', 'х', 'ј', 'a'};
    //char[] array = {'p', 'a', 'а', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'а'};
    //char[] array = {'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'k', 'a', 'a'};

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 'a') {
            count++;
        }
        //System.out.println(count);
    }
    System.out.println("Letter 'a' " + count + " times.");
}
```

I have some 'specific' problem here.
If I check first array, result is 2 instead 3.
If I check second array, result is 8 instead 10.
When I check third array, everything is OK.

You can uncomment the `System.out.println(count);` line and see strange way how it wrong count.

I want to know what is problem.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 10):

The first '`а`' is not an `a`.

http://unicode.scarfboy.com/?s=%D0%B0

Instead, it is `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER A` (encoded as `U+0430`), which is not the same as the `a` (encoded at `U+0061` with name `LATIN SMALL LETTER A`) that is normally used in the Latin alphabet. Java is not wrong, there are in fact two elements which are Latin `a`'s and encoded at the Latin `a`'s code point.

Going through the second array, this problem persists in the inputs, at least at the second '`a`' in the second array.

This appears because character evaluation like that you have above is done by comparing the code points (which also is why `char` types can be treated as integers). Under the hood, the computer is basically asking itself whether 61 is 430, which is obviously untrue.

Comment: seems like OP was typing using the wrong language settings

Comment: @ifly6 how do u detect it?

Comment: you can cast the characters to an `ìnt` and print them or view the source with a hex editor...

Comment: I detected it by copy-pasting the `a`'s into the Unicode search doohicky linked above, which quickly yielded the answer after one or two tries. You could also just cast them to `int` and see what's under the hood as described above.

Comment: @ifly6 Thank you. Can you or anybody else give me the simlest way to get this code work?
In fact, I need to count every letter in array that appears more then 1 time and show results. This was my start point, but I get that problem on start...

Comment: I would map the whole array into a `HashMap` which is set up to work as a `HashBag`.

Comment: @ifly6 I need simplest way, without using of collections, etc. We don't learn collections on college, that is reason why I need solution with basic level of java. Hope you understand me.

Comment: This is a one-liner which sets up the map and counts the objects: `IntStream.range(0, array.length).mapToObj(i -> array[i]).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))`

Comment: @ifly6 That is too advanced syntax for our level. :)
I need to find solution with loops, basic comparing, etc...